# Center multiple lines next to icon (glyph / font-awesome) with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, font-awesome

I want want to center some text next to some font-awesome icons. This works fine if the text only takes a single line. But as soon as it takes multiple lines, it stops working properly.

This is what I want:

```
|----|
|    | Very short text.
|----|

|----| Long long long long long long long long
|    | long long long long long long long long
|----| long long long long long long long text.
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: This is what it looks like now]

Here is my code: http://www.bootply.com/EVPYyfpcxw

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span class="myIcon fa fa-gear"></span>
  <span class="myText">Very short text.</span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="myIcon fa fa-gear"></span>
  <span class="myText">Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myIcon {
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:50px;
  line-height:75px;
  width: 75px;
}

.myText {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Two lines would probably be enough, but three would be nice.

Comment: just put it in a row with two columns

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="myIcon fa fa-gear"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <span class="myText">Very short text.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information regarding this please see:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Overall though this works by setting up both your icon and text in a row with two columns. Ensuring that each column is separate from the other and your long text wont bleed into the left column.

Comment: Clean, simple solution. I would probably consider giving some sort of explanation as to how/why this works - after all, us programmers *love* to know *how* things works, as well as that they work in the first place :)

Comment: adds link to grid documentation on getbs :)

Comment: I still feel that doesn't give any extra weight as to *why* your solution works...

Comment: I honestly don't even know if i can simplify html anymore it is just abundantly clear to me why it works... :(

Comment: Doesn't look centered to me! http://www.bootply.com/X6qSsuTrxb With 2 lines it might give the illusion that it is. But it is off by a few pixels. Change the font-size to something small and you'll see immediately that it is not centered.